# List of all words matching regular expression

Tags: python, regex

Let assume that I have some string: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
I need a list of all words with lenght more than 3. Can I do it with regular expressions?

e.g.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'some pattern')
result = pattern.search('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet').groups()
```

result contains 'Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor' and 'amet'.

EDITED:

The words I mean can only contains letters and numbers.

Comment: Do you mean ASCII letters, or are international letters like accented characters etc. also relevant?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> myre = re.compile(r"\w{4,}")
>>> myre.findall('Lorem, ipsum! dolor sit? amet...')
['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'amet']
```

Take note that in Python 3, where all strings are Unicode, this will also find words that use non-ASCII letters:

```
>>> import re
>>> myre = re.compile(r"\w{4,}")
>>> myre.findall('Lorem, ipsum! dolör sit? amet...')
['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolör', 'amet']
```

In Python 2, you'd have to use

```
>>> myre = re.compile(r"\w{4,}", re.UNICODE)
>>> myre.findall(u'Lorem, ipsum! dolör sit? amet...')
[u'Lorem', u'ipsum', u'dol\xf6r', u'amet']
```

Answer (score 2):

That is a tipical use case for list comprehensions in Python, which can
be used for filtering:

```
text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
result = [word for word in  pattern.findall(text) if len(word) > 3]
```

Comment: but what if I have "Lorem, ipsum"? This expression will return 'Lorem,' 'ipusm'. I don`t need comma.

Comment: Ok - I updated it to actually use the regex - the other sanswer was assuming you would not even need regex. The "findall" method of regexes is what you where missing.

Answer (score 2):

`pattern = re.compile("\w\w\w(\w+)")

result = pattern.search('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet').groups()`

Answer (score 0):

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(\S{4,})')
pattern.findall('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet')
['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'amet']
```

Comment: disregard my answer. Tim Pietzcker's handles cases like "sit?" properly